# Is developing an insight for someone the same as accepting them?

Tags: word-usage

A definition of insight is:

> The capacity to gain an accurate and deep intuitive understanding of a person or thing.

So according to this, if you develop an insight for a person, it means you've developed an understanding of the person. And an understanding of someone can lead to acceptance? For example, would it be correct to say,

> After refusing to accept Ben as his son for years, Jack finally developed an insight for Ben (and accepted him as his son).

Edit: Can you develop an insight *for* someone? After rereading, that part seems a little iffy.

Comment: I would probably say something more along the lines of _Jack finally grew to understand Ben_. "Insight" seems like a rather impersonal word to apply to an individual, although one could easily say, _developed an insight into Ben's_ **character**," meaning, "finally learned to understand Ben for who Ben really was."

Comment: I agree with J.R. but would also add that it is more common to see "insight" used with an attribute of a person, such as, "After many conversations, Jack developed an insight into Ben's fear of commitment."  or "...insight into Ben's need to be in control", etc.

Comment: Is it possible to "develop (an) insight for/into a situation"? 
(again, using 'insight' is confusing me, and I'm not sure if it's better with the *an* or without...) i.e. what would be the proper or common usage of *insight* when it's for a "thing"?
(The capacity to gain an accurate and deep intuitive understanding of a person or *thing*.)

Comment: See the usage notes for the first definition of [_insight_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insight)

Comment: 'insight _into_...'

Comment: I think the word you are seeking is *understanding*: After refusing to accept Ben as his son for years, Jack finally came to *understand* Ben and accepted him as his son.

Comment: Well, it's just that I needed a word that I can use in a sentence where I say, "Person 1's ability to develop [insight, or a similar word] (into his son) and person 2's failure to develop [same word], which is needed for person 2 to learn from his mistakes, results in..." ...If that makes any sense. Basically, something you need in order to accept someone AND to be able to learn from your mistakes. Insight was the only thing I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't [develop an insight **for**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%27m%20down%20with%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uYX4ULu_K5Go0AXQzYDgCw&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1990,cd_max:1/1/2000&tbm=bks#q=%22develop%20an%20insight%20for%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=fLj4UP2vMOmn0AW_roHwBA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864) something/someone (it's irrelevant whether it's a person, an area of knowledge, or whatever). That link has about a dozen relevant written instances of a usage I think is at least bordering on "illiterate".

You [develop an insight **into**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%27m%20down%20with%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uYX4ULu_K5Go0AXQzYDgCw&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1990,cd_max:1/1/2000&tbm=bks#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22develop%20an%20insight%20into%22&oq=%22develop%20an%20insight%20into%22&gs_l=serp.3...253493.256258.4.256586.8.8.0.0.0.0.54.381.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.812t2VHHmA0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864) something, as per those 5,590 instances.

For me personally, the idea that a father might need to gain insights into his (adopted?) son before "accepting" him sounds rather odd, but I assume this is a matter of culture rather than language.

Like *I see = I understand*, the word *insight* is a vision-based metaphor. In other tactile metaphors *(have a grasp **of**/handle **on**/feel **for** [something])*, the preposition varies according to the particular noun used to mean *understanding/knowledge/competence/control*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, however it would be better to use "insight into" instead of "insight for." Also, it does feel a little impersonal as a commenter said so I wouldn't necessarily use it in that exact case in your question. Grammatically, however, it is fine.

Comment: Though I have insight for the necessity for computer languages, I have yet to have any real insight into they actually work. Though he has developed an insight for Ben's existence, he does not have any insight into the deep recesses of Ben's mind.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: I don't think your first or third instances are at all valid uses of the word "insight", quite apart from "for" being a non-standard preposition. In both cases you just mean you're *aware of/acknowledge*. Your second lacks the word *"how"*, but I assume that's just a typo.

Comment: @cbbcbail
Even if the grammar is fine, would you say the **usage** is incorrect (based on the context)?

Comment: @Blue I would say the usage is unlikely. But of course it really does depend on that instance. Maybe his dad finally accepted him on a personal level after having an epiphany of what Ben was seeing.